# Using `except NameError:` for initialization of variables

Tags: python

The usual ("traditional") way of initializing certain kinds of objects prior to using them has always seemed awkward to me.

As a simple example, I often see code that looks like this:

```
my_list = []

for _ in some_iterator:
    # some complicated calculation for the NEXT list item
    my_list.append(NEXT)
```

To make matters worse, there are many situations in which subsequent items are dependent upon the values of prior items, or the first item:

```
FIRST = # some complicated multi-line calculation for FIRST list item
my_list = [FIRST]

for _ in some_iterator:
    # code to skip the first item creation since it is already there
    # some complicated calculation for the NEXT list item
    my_list.append(NEXT)
```

In order to avoid this, lately I have been doing the following quite a bit:

```
for _ in some_iterator:
    try:
        # some complicated calculation for the NEXT list item
        my_list.append(NEXT)
    except NameError:
        # come complicated calculation for FIRST list item
        my_list = [FIRST]
```

To further explain why I have begun to prefer the second way of doing things: it seems as if the task being undertaken - calculating `my_list` of things - ought to be encapsulated in its own block of code, and the initial item calculation and/or creation of the empty list in the traditional manner seems inconsistent with EAFP. Using the second method, the existence of `my_list` is assumed, and the "meat" of the procedure - the part anyone reading the code is most likely to be interested in - appears first. I recognize these are probably completely subjective judgments, so ultimately this is just an explanation; this aspect of the discussion has very little to do with my actual question.

My actual question is: are there any objective reasons, in general (i.e., without having specific situational code and running speed tests), to prefer one over the other? Or is this purely a matter of taste, and/or completely dependent upon the actual situation?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. First, you are invoking extra code and effort that isn't even needed (the `try/except` block), and second, now you can't use `my_list` outside of the scope of the `for` loop. Declaring/defining variables before use and within the scope they are needed is the most readable, maintainable code imho.

Comment: There have been three close votes in less than a few minutes because of "Primarily opinion-based". I understand the consensus may turn out to be that this is purely a matter of opinion. However, the only way to determine that for sure would be to at least leave the question open for more than 5 minutes. Sheesh.

Comment: Note that if the computation of `FIRST` throws, you may be left with either an empty list or a still undefined `my_list`.

Comment: @stevieb That's not true - you can use my_list outside of the loop. Try it. As to your third point, that's your opinion. I'm asking for objective reasons to prefer one or the other.

Comment: @Christoph Well, if FIRST does throw, you're guaranteed to get a `NameError` (later) when you try to use my_list. This is roughly equivalent to the first way; only difference is you'll get the error earlier (when trying to append to the list). To avoid the error you can have a nested `try:` block for the calculation of `FIRST`. I don't think your concern has much bearing on the question, in any case. Could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two reasons to prefer the "traditional" way:

1. If `my_list` happens to exist already, you never execute `my_list = [FIRST]`.
2. `NameError`s raised in the `try` block for reasons other than the one you intended will be obscured and cannot be handled properly.